# Optocoupler or DC/DC-converter for generation of trigger voltage

Tags: dc-dc-converter, opto-isolator, coupling

In my project I would like to trigger an external device with my electronic trigger system. The trigger voltage of the trigger system is 5 V, while the external device needs 24 V to be triggered. In addition to the trigger input the external device also has one pin for VCC (24 V) and one for GND. The current flowing is a few mA at max.

To be able to trigger my external device from my trigger system my initial approach was to use an optocoupler. Nevertheless, some colleagues also proposed using a DC/DC-converter.

Would that be a better solution? Or is there something completely different I have not considered yet?

Comment: ask colleagues why DC/DC converter would be a better solution ... maybe they have into that you have not presented

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, the external device supplies three nodes: +24 V, GND, and TRIGGER. Is that correct?

Comment: @jonk: Yes, with TRIGGER being the input for the trigger signal

Comment: A DC-DC converter seems like the wrong solution, unless as @jsotola said there's information we're lacking.  An optocoupler could work, do you need galvanic isolation between the trigger and the external device?  Otherwise a simple level shifter seems like the way forward.

Comment: @arc_lupus It is perhaps likely that a workable solution (whether galvanically isolated or not) can be suggested -- once you decide about the need for isolation. But it would be helpful as a double-check to know the device you are triggering. We'd be able to gather input specifications for trigger itself including thresholds, noise immunity, etc. and also some idea about signaling rates and/or edges (slew rates) and a host of other things that would take too long to write here. Are you willing to open your hand a bit and let us see what's being triggered?

Comment: @jonk: I don't have much more information either, I'm still working on getting those

Comment: @arc_lupus Perhaps this question is a little premature then? You may not even know if isolation is needed, yet...